# How do I create a separate application thread pool for my ISAPI extension?

Tags: c++, iis, isapi-extension

I created an ISAPI Extension in C++ that is a host for code written in the PowerBuilder programming language. This page recommends creating my own thread pool. Unfortunately it doesn't explain how to do that.

[Designing High-Performance ISAPI Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525640(v=vs.90))

One idea I had was to write a Windows Service and use Winsock to communicate between the ISAPI Extension and the service where the PowerBuilder code would be processed. Is it possible for the service to take over the client connection or does the extension have to wait for the service to send it the data to be returned to the client?

Is there another way of doing it that would be better? An example would be awesome.

Comment: That article was too old to be followed any more, and ISAPI has been proven to be one of worst option to extend IIS (PHP ISAPI was more troublesome than the benefits it brought). Today, you should develop your own application server to host PowerBuilder code (consider what Java/Go/Node.js does) and then use IIS as a reverse proxy in front.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps you can answer another question I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256486/c-sharp-web-app-can-access-network-shares-but-my-isapi-extension-cannot-why
PowerBuilder code in the ISAPI extension cannot access network files, even when the App Pool Identity is my own login. C# web apps have no problem.